# save edited image with frame sticker

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimage

Hello In my application user can pick image add filters , stickers , emoji and frames in image , i did this by adding image on it for frame i add another image on it and so on , in simple multiple images on Main Image but when i save original image i did't see any frame emoji in it please help me.
I want to save image with all things i am using marker , textview also in this app .
i am saving image in this way

```
 let yourDataImagePNG = mainImageviewOutlet.image!.pngData()
         UserDefaults().set(yourDataImagePNG, forKey: "image")
```

Comment: Please provide more info about your image setup and what exactly goes wrong. E.g. is `yourDataImagePNG` empty? If you set a breakpoint in the line after the `let`, can you inspect the PNG data in the debugger, and does it show an image? If so, only the base image?

Comment: no yourDataImagePNG is not empty , it just shows original image without any edited  things like frame emoji